# Monitoring reports for abnormal conditions

Tags: monitoring

I have several HTTP APIs which generate several reports with raw data every day. I need a monitoring service that can hit an URI in those APIs, retrieve data, analyze it following some predefined rules -- which might be written in code, python preferable -- and trigger a warning, that might be an email or an HTTP request to post a message on a team chat service like Slack.

It's not server monitoring. We have Nagios, Sensu, New Relic, etc, that already do that for us. It's for monitoring business results. Any suggestions on something simple, that doesn't have a lot of requirements?

Comment: Monitoring service: `cron`. Hit an URI, retrieve data: `wget`. Analyze it: `python`. Send mail: `mail`. HTTP request: `curl`. Could that make an answer? I have the feeling that your request is too narrow and/or we have not enough information of what you want to achieve.